# Does running some commands on terminal with sudo permission consume more RAM?

Tags: mac, command-line, memory

I routinely need to run large programs for testing purposes on a Mac. And they have a lot of sudo commands. Most of the commands have to do with FTP and string manipulations in plists.

I know it's silly but do commands run with sudo permission require more RAM? I'm talking around 5-6 GB RAM utilisation which never goes down even after the program has run its course. Currently, the only solution is to reboot the PC.

Comment: A program doesn't need memory after it has run. Can you please use Activity Monitor to look at the applications using most memory and add a screenshot to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes, there could be memory leaks etc in the application which only trigger when the application runs with administrative or root privileges. In practice the chance for this is probably rather small, and I would look for issues elsewhere first.